# Scipy stats.mode is not returning maximum occurred value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scipy, mode

I am new to scipy. I am trying to get maximum occurred value of string column.

**Here is my Code:**

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.stats import mode

    print ("Maximum Occurence of Store Owner " + str(mode(df_units["StoreOwner"], nan_policy='omit').mode[0]))
```

**Here is first few rows of Store Owner Data:**

```
    0    Muhammed MacIntyre
    1          Barry French
    2          Barry French
    3         Clay Rozendal
    4        Carlos Soltero
```

In above code I am trying to get maximum occured store Owner value in from the datframe. But it is returning all the values as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
pdf = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']))
pdf.A.value_counts().idxmax()
```

This gives you the value that occured most frequently in the column `A` of the dataframe `pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in a Pandas `Series` called `ser`, you can get the most frequently occurring string by:

```
ser.value_counts()[ser.value_counts().index.max()]
```